# WMI Class is failed to initialize or it gives access violation

Tags: visual-c++, com, wmi

Hi i am fetching hadrware information. IT build successfully but i am   facing two big issue.

Issue 1 :
When i select Project Properties/Configuration Properties/General/Character Set/Multi-byte Character Set In that case its going fail to give initialize COM Library. here is littlefor that

```
HRESULT hreshard;

        // Initialize COM.
        hreshard =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
        if (FAILED(hreshard))
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to initialize COM library. "));
            return false;                                                   // Program is going fail here and not able to give any information.
        }
```

Issue 2 :
When i select Project Properties/Configuration Properties/General/Character Set/Unicode  Charater-Set In that case its crash in winmain.cpp file with unanhandled exception at 0x53a994ea (mfc100ud.dll) in TM_app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Please give me suggestions.